# Determine the directory based on a default directory

Tags: regex, perl

I want to split out a directory based on a given directory path with comparison to a default directory in perl preferably in regex. I have two default directories, lets say /root/demo/ and /etc/demo/.

Given a directory path, 
lets say 
/root/demo/home/test/sample/somefile.txt OR 
/etc/demo/home/test/sample/somefile.txt,

I want to extract the /home/test/sample/somefile.txt from the given directory path. Kindly assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Use `\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) to discard the previously matched characters.

```
\/(?:root|etc)\/demo\K\S+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kX9tQ2/3)

Comment: or `\/(?:root|etc)\/demo\K.*?\.\w+(?=\s|$)`

Comment: Thanks , but I want to have a generic regex, this regex checks for /root/demo/ or /etc/demo/ . My default directory can be a n level directory, like:/etc/demo/a/b/ or /root/demo/a/b/. Bascially to convey the default directory are configurable to a n level depth directory.

Comment: could you post some more examples along with the expected output?

Comment: oh, i totally confused. What do you mean by default directory?

Comment: Example1- Default directory: /root/demo/ OR /etc/demo/
Given Directory Path: /root/demo/test/some/file.txt
OutPut: /test/some/file.txt

Example2: Default directory: /root/demo/a/ OR /etc/demo/a/
Given Path: /root/demo/a/some/file/abc.txt
OutPut:/some/file/abc.txt

The default directories are configurable to any n level depth directory.

The basic idea is to remove the default directory as provided from given directory path, as in the above /etc/demo/ OR /root/demo/ OR /etc/demo/a/ OR /root/demo/a/ was removed from the given path of /root/demo/test/some/file.txt & /root/demo/a/some/file/abc.txt

Answer (score 1):

Build your list of prefix dirs into a regex [alteration](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-this-or-that).  Be sure to sort by [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) descending, and also to use [`quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html).

The following demonstrates:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @dirs = qw(
    /root/demo
    /etc/demo
);

# Sorted by length descending in case there are subdirs.
my $list_dirs = join '|', map {quotemeta} sort { length($b) <=> length($a) } @dirs;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if ( my ($subdir) = m{^(?:$list_dirs)(/.*)} ) {
        print "$subdir\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
/root/demo/home/test/sample/someroot.txt
/etc/demo/home/test/sample/someetc.txt
```

Outputs:

```
/home/test/sample/someroot.txt
/home/test/sample/someetc.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way using quotemeta.

Perl sample:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @defaults = ('/root/demo/', '/etc/demo/');

$/ = undef;
my $testdata = <DATA>;

my $regex = '(?:' . join( '|', map(quotemeta($_), @defaults) ) . ')(\S*)';
print $regex, "\n\n";

while ( $testdata =~ /$regex/g )
{
    print "Found /$1\n";
}

__DATA__

/root/demo/home/test/sample/somefile.txt
/etc/demo/home/test/sample/somefile.txt
```

Output:

```
(?:\/root\/demo\/|\/etc\/demo\/)(\S*)

Found /home/test/sample/somefile.txt
Found /home/test/sample/somefile.txt
```